# Como publicar imagen en endpoint con asp net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas estoy tratando de publicar una imagen por un endpoint y para eso necesito recibir un parámetro. El método funciona bien pero siempre y cuando no le envie un . en la ruta ej:  api/imagenes/GetImagenLink/xxxxx

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si le pongo un punto para especificar el formato ej :api/imagenes/GetImagenLink/xxxxx.jpg entonces revienta y da error.

Como puedo recibir algo como imagen.png como parámetro en la URL ????

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/imagenes/GetImagenLink/{articulo}")]
    // GET: api/Imagenes
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetImagenLink(string articulo)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage();

        try
        {

            noef.controllers.selects consulta = new noef.controllers.selects();

            noef.models.Conexion conexion = new noef.models.Conexion
            {
                Servidor = "xxxxxx",
                BD = "xxxxx",
                Usuario = "xxx",
                Password = "xxx"
            };

            string[] split = articulo.Split('.');

            List<object> objetos = await consulta.SelectFromDatabase(conexion, $"SELECT  [ARTICULO],[FOTO],[ARCHIVO] FROM xxxxx where ARTICULO = '{split[0]}'");




 var serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objetos, Formatting.Indented);

            var desereal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Respuesta>>(serial);

            var source = desereal.Where(x => x.Columna.ToString() == "FOTO").FirstOrDefault();



            var array = source.Valor;

            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(Convert.FromBase64String(array.ToString()));

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/split[1]");


            result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception d)
        {

            result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            return result;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta poniento una `/` al final de la url, como ser

```
http://{sitio}/api/imagenes/GetImagenLink/xxxxx.jpg/
```

recuerdo que esto permitia cerrar le uri y definir el parametro

Comment: No me sirve así. Le explico porque. Lo que quiero es pasarle esa url como source de una imagen en xamarin forms. Entonces necesito que sea un URL como esta :  https://www.tekcrispy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/bancos-imagenes-gratis-640x422.jpg

Comment: Resulta que las url donde esta el nombre de la imagen.png o jpg o algo si lo agarra el source de xamarin como esta:  https://www.tekcrispy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/bancos-imagenes-gratis-640x422.jpg ,  pero si la paso como la que yo hice : http://localhost/api/imagenes/GetImagen/4152544150 , entonces no muestra nada.

Comment: edite la respuesta, valida si aplica lo que comento

Comment: Correcto. Eso era todo el problema!! Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Usa parametro en la URL

```
[System.Web.Http.Route(**"api/imagenes/GetImagenLink"**)]
    // GET: api/Imagenes
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetImagenLink(**[FromUri]** string articulo)
    {
```

Tu URL se veria asi: api/imagenes/GetImagenLink?articulo=xxxxx.jpg

Espero te sirva.